# Color of column in columnchart based on values from store in extJS 3.4

Tags: extjs, charts

I have a jsonstore

```
var rankingStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: './get-ranking-stats.php',
    root: 'item',
    fields: ['name', 'click', 'foto','pdf', 'gid', 'type'],
    baseParams: {end: getToday(), start: getOneWeekBefore(), typ: 'all'},
    autoLoad: true
})
```

and column chart based on it:

```
var statis2 =  new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Ranking',
    width: '60%',
    height: 500,
    items: {
        xtype: 'columnchart',
        store: rankingStore,
        xField: 'name',
        id: 'mainChart2',
        yField: 'click',
        extraStyle: {
           xAxis: {
                labelRotation: -90
            }
        },
    series: [{
            type: 'column',
            displayName: 'Click counter',
            yField: 'click',
            style: {
                mode: 'stretch',
                color:0x99BBE8
            }
        }]



    }
});
```

All coulms have the same colour. What I want is to heve different colours based on 'type' value from jsonstore. How to create rule like that?

Answer (score 3):

user before render event of chart after that u add own custom color in chart.

```
beforerender: function(chart, record, index, series){
if(record.data.type=="Somthing"){
// add own custom css
    }
    },
```

Comment: actually [beforerender](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Component.html#Ext-Component-event-beforerender) in extjs 3.4 has other parameters than you have mentioned